# How do I replace a worn isolation valve which is partially recessed into a tiled wall?

Tags: bathroom, tile, valve

The outer screw on an isolation valve in our bathroom has been worn away:

[image: image 1]

We believe it needs to be replaced. The valve itself is partially recessed into the bathroom's tiled wall:

[image: image 2]

We have a few questions:

1. Is there a way to use the isolation valve effectively in its current state (i.e. without having to replace it)?
2. If we do need to replace it, is there a way to do it without causing damaging to the surrounding tiles? (I believe I have the skill to replace the valve itself, but probably not to deal with the related tile work.)
3. Approximately how much should we expect to pay a professional for the replacement / clean-up job (UK)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the valve stem and handle were cut off!!

The valve will need replacement.

Access for replacement will require removing at least one tile.

Cost estimates are something you will get from bids in your locale.